# Need help to understand a kernel "deadlock" in armhf kernel 5.4

Tags: kernel, deadlock, spinlock

I'm struggling to understand a condition that occurs rarely (MTBF measured in weeks to months), but results in a fatal kernel lockup when it does.

The environment is kernel 5.4.0, running on a dual-core ARM A9 32-bit (armhf) processor in an AMD/Xilinx Zynq 7020 SoC.
I've been able to examine stack traces on two failed devices using the Xilinx Vitis system debugger. In both cases, both cores were waiting for (attempting to lock) the same spinlock. The spinlock is the `pi_lock` member of the `struct task_struct` structure associated with a threaded IRQ handler.

Core #0 is running the idle process, responding to an interrupt, attempting to wake up the IRQ handler thread. Core #1 is reading the `/proc/<PID>/stat` sysfs pseudofile associated with the IRQ handler thread (while reading all of the sysfs pseudofiles of the form `/proc/<PID>/stat` on behalf of `pidof`, probably at the request of `sessionclean`, invoked by `apache2`).

The interrupt being handled on one device is for the BQ25890 battery charger (asserted ~zero to 10 times per second, and on the other device, for a custom kernel module (~100/sec.). Both interrupts use the default primary IRQ handler.

The current hypothesis is that that core #0 got stuck first, followed some time later by core #1, rather than both occurring simultaneously, but this is speculative.

Stack traces for the two cores and threaded IRQ handler source for one of the devices are below.

**Questions**

Is there enough information in the stack traces to provide a clue as to what went wrong? If so, what went wrong? If not, what additional information is needed? One of the devices is still available, and some (not all) variables can be interrogated.
Is the fact that interrupts are disabled (cpsr.i == 1 for both cores) significant?

Please note that because of the extremely long time between failures, black-box testing techniques - that is, making changes in order to observe the result - are not practical.

**ARM Cortex-A9 MPCore #0 (Suspended)**

```
0x80165d68: ./include/linux/compiler.h, line 199
0x80165d68 arch_spin_lock(): .../arch/arm/include/asm/spinlock.h, line 75
0x8076f774: ./include/linux/spinlock.h, line 193
0x8076f774: ...include/linux/spinlock_api_smp.h, line 119
0x8076f774 _raw_spin_lock_irqsave(): kernel/locking/spinlock.c, line 159
0x8014a394 try_to_wake_up(): kernel/sched/core.c, line 2551
0x8014a724 wake_up_process(): kernel/sched/core.c, line 2667
0x8016f600 __irq_wake_thread(): kernel/irq/handle.c, line 134
0x8016f820 __handle_irq_event_percpu(): kernel/irq/handle.c, line 167
0x8016f888 handle_irq_event_percpu(): kernel/irq/handle.c, line 189
0x8016f924 handle_irq_event(): kernel/irq/handle.c, line 206
0x80174230 handle_level_irq(): kernel/irq/chip.c, line 650
0x8016e808: ./include/linux/irqdesc.h, line 156
0x8016e808 generic_handle_irq(): kernel/irq/irqdesc.c, line 644
0x80447a20: drivers/gpio/gpio-zynq.c, line 632
0x80447a20 zynq_gpio_irqhandler(): drivers/gpio/gpio-zynq.c, line 661
0x8016e808: ./include/linux/irqdesc.h, line 156
0x8016e808 generic_handle_irq(): kernel/irq/irqdesc.c, line 644
0x8016eec4 __handle_domain_irq(): kernel/irq/irqdesc.c, line 681
0x80102300: ./include/linux/irqdesc.h, line 174
0x80102300 gic_handle_irq(): drivers/irqchip/irq-gic.c, line 383
0x80101a70 __irq_svc(): arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S, line 212
0x805827c0 cpuidle_enter_state(): .../arch/arm/include/asm/irqflags.h, line 39
0x805829d8 cpuidle_enter(): drivers/cpuidle/cpuidle.c, line 344
0x8014ecf0: kernel/sched/idle.c, line 117
0x8014ecf0: kernel/sched/idle.c, line 201
0x8014ecf0 do_idle(): kernel/sched/idle.c, line 263
0x8014eeac cpu_startup_entry(): kernel/sched/idle.c, line 355
0x80769828 rest_init(): init/main.c, line 451
0x80c00b30 arch_call_rest_init(): init/main.c, line 572
0x80c00f78 start_kernel(): init/main.c, line 784
0x00000000
0x00000000
```

**The offending lock**

```
lock    arch_spinlock_t *   {{slock=0x94449440, tickets={owner=0x9440, next=0x9444}}}   
    slock   u32 0x94449440  
    tickets struct __raw_tickets    {owner=0x9440, next=0x9444} 
        owner   u16 0x9440  
        next    u16 0x9444
```

**Threaded IRQ handler source**

Note that this code does not appear in the call stacks, but is the code for the thread that core #0 is attempting to wake up.

On one of the devices:

```
static irqreturn_t bq25890_irq_handler_thread(int irq, void *private)
{
    struct bq25890_device *bq = private;
    int ret;
    struct bq25890_state state;

    ret = bq25890_get_chip_state(bq, &state);
    if (ret < 0)
        goto handled;

    if (!bq25890_state_changed(bq, &state))
        goto handled;

    bq25890_handle_state_change(bq, &state);

    mutex_lock(&bq->lock);
    bq->state = state;
    mutex_unlock(&bq->lock);

    power_supply_changed(bq->charger);

handled:
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

On the other device:

```
static irqreturn_t core100_irq_handler( int irq, void* data )
{
    struct core100_drvdata* p_info;
    struct core100_block_header* next;
    unsigned long iflags;
    p_info = ( struct core100_drvdata* ) data;
    if ( ( p_info->state != state_reading ) && ( p_info->state != state_writing ) )
    {
        return IRQ_HANDLED;
    }
    next = &p_info->current_block->next->header;
    next->count_at_pps = read_register( p_info->count_pps_register );
    next->frc_at_pps = read_register( p_info->frc_pps_register );
    next->count = adc_counter();
    next->frc = free_running_counter();
    spin_lock_irqsave( &p_info->state_lock, iflags );
    p_info->dma_head += bytes_per_block( p_info );
    if ( p_info->dma_head - p_info->dma_tail > bytes_per_buffer( p_info ) )
    {
        p_info->dma_tail = p_info->dma_head - bytes_per_buffer( p_info );
    }
    p_info->current_block = p_info->current_block->next;
    wake_up_interruptible( &p_info->wq );
    spin_unlock_irqrestore( &p_info->state_lock, iflags );
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

Kernel source:
[struct task_struct][1]

**ARM Cortex-A9 MPCore #1 (Suspended)**

```
0x80165d68: ./include/linux/compiler.h, line 199
0x80165d68 arch_spin_lock(): .../arch/arm/include/asm/spinlock.h, line 75
0x8076f774: ./include/linux/spinlock.h, line 193
0x8076f774: ...include/linux/spinlock_api_smp.h, line 119
0x8076f774 _raw_spin_lock_irqsave(): kernel/locking/spinlock.c, line 159
0x80148914 task_rq_lock(): kernel/sched/core.c, line 109
0x8014e22c: kernel/sched/cputime.c, line 281
0x8014e22c thread_group_cputime(): kernel/sched/cputime.c, line 326
0x8014e650 thread_group_cputime_adjusted(): kernel/sched/cputime.c, line 678
0x802ccb5c do_task_stat(): fs/proc/array.c, line 510
0x802cdaf4 proc_tgid_stat(): fs/proc/array.c, line 632
0x802c7c0c proc_single_show(): fs/proc/base.c, line 756
0x80281b18 seq_read(): fs/seq_file.c, line 229
0x8025dd1c __vfs_read(): fs/read_write.c, line 425
0x8025de60 vfs_read(): fs/read_write.c, line 461
0x8025e088 ksys_read(): fs/read_write.c, line 587
0x8025e0ec: fs/read_write.c, line 597
0x8025e0ec __se_sys_read(): fs/read_write.c, line 595
0x80101000 __idmap_text_end()
0x76e627e6
0x76edc616
```

Here's an alternative view, showing the calls stacks associated with their calling processes. "Swapper" is an archaic term for the idle process:

```
Kernel  
    0 swapper/0        (Suspended), ARM Cortex-A9 MPCore #0 
        0x80165d68: ./include/linux/compiler.h, line 199    
        0x80165d68 arch_spin_lock(): .../arch/arm/include/asm/spinlock.h, line 75   
        0x8076f774: ./include/linux/spinlock.h, line 193    
        0x8076f774: ...include/linux/spinlock_api_smp.h, line 119   
        0x8076f774 _raw_spin_lock_irqsave(): kernel/locking/spinlock.c, line 159    

11950 pidof 
    11950 (Suspended), ARM Cortex-A9 MPCore #1  
        0x80165d68: ./include/linux/compiler.h, line 199    
        0x80165d68 arch_spin_lock(): .../arch/arm/include/asm/spinlock.h, line 75   
        0x8076f774: ./include/linux/spinlock.h, line 193    
        0x8076f774: ...include/linux/spinlock_api_smp.h, line 119   
        0x8076f774 _raw_spin_lock_irqsave(): kernel/locking/spinlock.c, line 159
```

**RCU Configuration**

```
# RCU Subsystem
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU=y
# CONFIG_RCU_EXPERT is not set
CONFIG_SRCU=y
CONFIG_TREE_SRCU=y
CONFIG_TASKS_RCU=y
CONFIG_RCU_STALL_COMMON=y
CONFIG_RCU_NEED_SEGCBLIST=y
# end of RCU Subsystem
# RCU Debugging
# CONFIG_RCU_PERF_TEST is not set
# CONFIG_RCU_TORTURE_TEST is not set
CONFIG_RCU_CPU_STALL_TIMEOUT=21
# CONFIG_RCU_TRACE is not set
# CONFIG_RCU_EQS_DEBUG is not set
# end of RCU Debugging
```

**Kernel Thread Prioities**

```
# ps -eo pid,tid,class,rtprio,ni,pri,wchan:14,comm | grep -E '(PID|bq25890|raw_dma)'
  PID   TID CLS RTPRIO  NI PRI WCHAN          COMMAND
  214   214 FF      50   -  90 irq_thread     irq/59-bq25890_
  229   229 FF      50   -  90 irq_thread     irq/60-raw_dma
```

**Processor Status Registers**
On at least one failed system, the `interrupt disable` bit is set on both processors. That seems wrong, although the `fast interrupt disable` bit is not set. If I set a breakpoint in `arch_spin_lock()` on a working system, the interrupt disable bit is not set.
It would seem that the only way for the spinlock to be released is in response to an interrupt, since the active threads on both cores aren't going to do it.

```
Core #0
cpsr    200f0193    537854355   
    n   0   0   Negative condition code flag    
    z   0   0   Zero condition code flag    
    c   1   1   Carry condition code flag   
    v   0   0   Overflow condition code flag    
    q   0   0   Cumulative saturation flag  
    it  00  0   If-Then execution state bits    
    j   0   0   Jazelle bit 
    ge  f   15  SIMD Greater than or Equal flags    
    e   0   0   Endianness execution state bit  
    a   1   1   Asynchronous abort disable bit  
    i   1   1   Interrupt disable bit   
    f   0   0   Fast interrupt disable bit  
    t   0   0   Thumb execution state bit   
    m   13  19  Mode field  
irq 
    sp  80d94400    2161722368  
    lr  80101e20    2148539936  
    spsr    200f0193    537854355   
        n   0   0   Negative condition code flag    
        z   0   0   Zero condition code flag    
        c   1   1   Carry condition code flag   
        v   0   0   Overflow condition code flag    
        q   0   0   Cumulative saturation flag  
        it  00  0   If-Then execution state bits    
        j   0   0   Jazelle bit 
        ge  f   15  SIMD Greater than or Equal flags    
        e   0   0   Endianness execution state bit  
        a   1   1   Asynchronous abort disable bit  
        i   1   1   Interrupt disable bit   
        f   0   0   Fast interrupt disable bit  
        t   0   0   Thumb execution state bit   
        m   13  19  Mode field  

Core #1
cpsr    200f0093    537854099   
    n   0   0   Negative condition code flag    
    z   0   0   Zero condition code flag    
    c   1   1   Carry condition code flag   
    v   0   0   Overflow condition code flag    
    q   0   0   Cumulative saturation flag  
    it  00  0   If-Then execution state bits    
    j   0   0   Jazelle bit 
    ge  f   15  SIMD Greater than or Equal flags    
    e   0   0   Endianness execution state bit  
    a   0   0   Asynchronous abort disable bit  
    i   1   1   Interrupt disable bit   
    f   0   0   Fast interrupt disable bit  
    t   0   0   Thumb execution state bit   
    m   13  19  Mode field  
irq 
    sp  80d94440    2161722432  
    lr  80101a00    2148538880  
    spsr    60030193    1610809747  
        n   0   0   Negative condition code flag    
        z   1   1   Zero condition code flag    
        c   1   1   Carry condition code flag   
        v   0   0   Overflow condition code flag    
        q   0   0   Cumulative saturation flag  
        it  00  0   If-Then execution state bits    
        j   0   0   Jazelle bit 
        ge  3   3   SIMD Greater than or Equal flags    
        e   0   0   Endianness execution state bit  
        a   1   1   Asynchronous abort disable bit  
        i   1   1   Interrupt disable bit   
        f   0   0   Fast interrupt disable bit  
        t   0   0   Thumb execution state bit   
        m   13  19  Mode field
```

Comment: Possibly OT however what are your kernel CONFIG_*_RCU* settings (& realtime priority of the associated kernel threads ? Also what is the realtime priority of the IRQ handler thread ?

Comment: @MC68020 - Thanks. I've edited my post to include RCU configuration, and the PID-relative stack displays. Core #0 is running the swapper process, PID 0. As I understand it, that should preempt all other processes. Core #1 is running under the "pidof" process, which runs only occasionally, but should have a normal non-RT priority, as it is just cleaning up dead PHP sessions.
There are actually no RT threads in the system, except for an NTP service thread. Of course, the IRQ handler threads are not running at the time of the failure.

Comment: Pardon me I am at lost with your last comment. "Core #0 is running the swapper process" Do you mean kswapd ? In which case this is not pid 0 (which is a pure abstraction) and wont preempt any other process since it is scheduled SCHED_OTHER. " No RT threads in the system ? even not [migration] threads ?

Comment: If you get means to rebuild your kernel, I'd suggest to set CONFIG_RCU_EXPERT, this enabling you to set CONFIG_RCU_BOOST.

Comment: @MC68020 - Refer to the "alternative thread view" that I added to my post. The Debugger shows two views - one that shows the stack for each core, and one that shows the processes in the system, with the stack for the two processes that are running on the cores. Core #0 is listed under PID 0, and name "swapper/0." My understanding of "swapper's" priority was off the mark. A little Googling identifies it as the idle process.

Comment: Does the concept of a scheduling policy even apply to migration threads? In any event they won't be different than any other Linux system - certainly I've done nothing to alter them.